# RavenDB - write to documents from transformer

Tags: ravendb

I've got an index that goes over a huge number of documents, and then a transformer that shapes a return and does some math logic to them.

Is it possible to write back to a field on the documents from within the transformer or index, instead of having to fetch the data and send another request to write to each document?

So for example, I have documents `Scores`, each has a property called `Values` that is a `IList<double>`.

I have an index that gets all of them, and a Transformer that does some math based on other properties in the retrieved documents.

```
var results = 
    session
        .Query<Score, ScoresByName>()
        .TransformWith<ScoresTransformer, ScoresTransformer.Result>()
        .ToList();
```

Is it possible to write to each document before it ever comes back to me?

Basically, after the transformer runs, each document has new information in its `Values` property. I wish to just write that to the document; Otherwise, I have to run this query and transformer, then either write to each document in a loop, or run a patch request. I'd like to avoid that if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scripted index results for this:

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/server/bundles/scripted-index-results

Comment: Okay, I'm reading over this and it makes sense, but I'm confused about something. When I was designing my transformer, you told me that what I needed to do was better suited to a transformer. So I guess I'm asking... does this scripted index thing work with the results of a transformer? Or do I need to move all of my logic into an index?

Comment: You want to use a transformer to write to the database again. That isn't something transformers _do_. This is when you want to transform the query at read time.

Comment: For writing to the db, you use something like the scripted index results.